# Packages, Files and Getting simple code to run!

Tags: java

I have SimpleSphere.java and TestClass.java stored in a folder called MyPackage.

[image]
[image]

Attempting to compile TestClass gives this error:

```
TestClass.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        SimpleSphere ball = new SimpleSphere(19.1);
        ^
  symbol:   class SimpleSphere
  location: class TestClass
TestClass.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        SimpleSphere ball = new SimpleSphere(19.1);
                            ^
  symbol:   class SimpleSphere
  location: class TestClass
2 errors
```

But I am fairly certain I have everything set up correctly (evidently I do not, and yet I remain stubborn!).  Also, even if these two files were not part of MyPackage, shouldn't JAVA look in the current directory as default and find SimpleSphere???

Comment: Looks like you're compiling the classes inside the package. Compile both classes outside package and set classpath as `MyPackage`, then try again.

Comment: Are you running your program through an IDE or manually? Because if you are doing it manually you have to compile `SimpleSphere` first followed by `TestClass`.

Comment: Never post a screenshot of code. Copy-paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're compiling the classes directly using `javac ClassName.java` inside the folder where they are located. You have to move one folder up and compile them since there.

Here's a sample of how the files should be located

```
- basePath
  - MyPackage
    + SimpleSphere.java
    + TestClass.java
```

In your cmd/shell:

```
# [basePath] javac MyPackage/SimpleSphere.java
# [basePath] javac MyPackage/TestClass.java
# [basePath] java MyPackage.TestClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving one folder up and then compiling.

Best of Luck.